# How to find absolute path to devices attached to Windows 10 machine (Like phones)

Tags: powershell, android

Whenever I attach my Android 10 phone to my Windows 10 Home machine, it show up as it's device name and it's shown path is "This PC\My Phone" which is not absolute and an alias of some sort. Gone are the days that phones would show up as plain drives I guess. *sighs*

Problem is I want to automate moving folders from the phone and using PowerShell I need to have it's absolute path or something as "This PC\My Phone" does not work.

So far I've tried these running from the destination folder in PowerShell:

```
Move-Item -Path "This PC\My Phone\Internal storage\SourceFolder" -Destination "C:\DestinationFolder"
```

and yields

```
Cannot find path 'C:\DestinationFolder\This PC\My Phone\Internal storage\SourceFolder' because it
```

does not exist.

I tried several options like showing full path in title bar and still shows "This Pc > My Phone" in the title bar.

I tried opening that device in Everything and showed up as:

```
"::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_12d1&pid_107e&mi_00#7&2d05eb6&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,,55668899840}\{00000009-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}\{0000007B-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}\"
```

But that didn't work in Move-Item.

Please note that I much rather not mess with Registry if possible.

Cheers.

Comment: There IS NO PATH to your phone.  Windows explorer FAKES it looking like a drive using a shell extension.  You *might* (depending on your skill) be able to use the ADB tool that comes with the Android development kit to automate doing file transfers but you certainly "have some learnin'" to do.  Your phone will need to have the "debug mode" set to use it.

Comment: A very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628092/how-to-reliably-copy-items-with-powershell-to-an-mtp-device

Comment: I'd be curious in hearing how it goes it you move rather than copy though. Just would be curious to hear it allows you to move those via command if you figure out the way to get it done. Here's another post too in case it has additional detail on potential solution(s): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094188/access-mtp-storage-with-system-io-from-powershell and this GitHub has a couple PowerScript ways to do this too potentially: https://github.com/nosalan/powershell-mtp-file-transfer